# Xamarin.forms: button event handler calling a method in a parent class using xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms, event-handling

Can this be done? What I am after is something like this:

```
<StackLayout x:Name="AParent">
    <StackLayout>
        <Button Text="Click me!" Clicked="AParent.OnButtonClicked()" />
    </StackLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

and in the codebehind for AParent:

```
    async void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Click!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, but I think what you're after is this. Specify your `Button` like this:

`<Button Text="Click me!" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />`

And in your code-behind you can do this:

```
void OnButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Click!");
}
```

It doesn't matter that the `Button` is nested inside other elements. These are not parent classes, but simply parents in the visual tree. All the objects are still in the same class and can be reached through the code-behind of that page.

Comment: You are right, think I didn't yet have a correct understanding of how the xaml files and the codebehind files work together to define a control. I'll have to read more about this. Thanks!